# Get 1:1 ratio between pgfplot's plot and the "document's sizes"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I was trying to get my pgfplot's plot lengths the same length proportion I get in the tikz coordinates outside of the plots for exemple.

Here's the image I use as exemplification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill] (0,4.5) coordinate[label={right:\footnotesize{(0,4.5)}}] circle (0.06);
\draw[fill] (6,0) coordinate[label={above:\footnotesize{(6,0)}}] circle (0.06);
\begin{axis}[
  width=6cm,
  height=4.5cm,
  axis lines=middle,
  unit vector ratio=1 1,
  xmax=6,
  ymax=4.5,
  xmin=0,
  ymin=0,
  samples=50,
  xtick distance=1,ytick distance=0.5,
  every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}
]
\addplot[domain=0:6] {1/\x^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have a 1:1 ratio between the axis length and the "coordinate ones", but I don't know how to manage that.

Thanks.

Comment: If you put your draw commands *inside* the `axis` environment, and issue `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`, you will use the same coordinates of your axis. BTW your `circle` command is using an obsolete syntax.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tips; could you tell me what is this updated syntax people are using?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; it's been here since forever (but to have it by default, you need to activate compatibility at least to version 1.11): https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you only need to add `[scale only axis]` to fix the width and height to match the screen coordinates.  The `[unit vector ratio]` or `[equal axis]` options are redundant.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill] (0,4.5) coordinate[label={right:\footnotesize{(0,4.5)}}] circle (0.06);
\draw[fill] (6,0) coordinate[label={above:\footnotesize{(6,0)}}] circle (0.06);
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
  width=6cm,
  height=4.5cm,
  axis lines=middle,
  xmax=6,
  ymax=4.5,
  xmin=0,
  ymin=0,
  samples=50,
  xtick distance=1,ytick distance=0.5,
  every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}
]
\addplot[domain=0:6] {1/\x^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot, very easy and simple.